In John Wick 2, why did it matter if John was killed before the "excommunicado" took effect?
Assuming the following facts about John Wick during the events of "John Wick 2" and "John Wick 3":



 John Wick had an open contract placed on him by Santino D'Antonio during the events of John Wick 2. (Because John killed Santino's sister (Gianna), Santino "had" to put a bounty on his sister's killer, even though he was the one who ordered the hit by enforcing his marker on John.) (A marker being a mandatory contract that the holder of said marker can use to demand services from the one to whom the contract was signed with. There are additional rules to this but for brevity: if you have established a marker with someone, you're allowed to demand that someone to do any one task you wish.)




 John Wick kills Santino in retaliation for being coerced into Santino's gambit play to take his sister seat on "The High Table" but does so on The Continental grounds. (By the rules of the universe, this is a disallowed action. "Business cannot be conducted on Continental grounds." as repeated throughout the movies and prequel show.)




 Winston, manager of The Continental, orders John Wick to be declared excommunicado (banished from all services connected to the Continental) and issues a death warrant on him for violating the one rule about such (see bullet point 2). The death warrant has an additional $7 MM to the one who kills John but is declared to go in to effect after the hour elapses.




 Winston, owing John for his friendship, delays the excommunicado order for one hour. He does this by taking him from his "home" (or remains thereof) and meeting him in the middle of Central Park. Setting John up with the hour. (This is at the end of John Wick 2 which takes place immediately before the start of John Wick 3.)



At the start of John Wick 3: Parabellum, someone tries to collect on this bounty. John remarks, it's "too early".
My question is, would it have mattered that John was killed "too early" given that he still had a bounty on him in the amount of $7 MM from Santino. Granted Santino was no longer at the head of the table as the D'Antonio's head but someone else within the D'Antonio family could still reward the bounty?
Was John Wick's original bounty, from Santino, still in effect?

The rules seem a little flexible (or have been retconned). There seems to be a consensus that the $14M bounty by the High Table only comes into effect after the Incommunicado takes effect. I assume Santino's bounty was cancelled as he's no longer around to pay it.

The criminal underworld in John Wick is bound by very tight and specific rules. No business on Continental grounds is one such rule. The rules relating to contracts and excommunication are also tight, specific ones. If a contract or an excommunication has a start time, that is part of the rules. Killing someone before the start time is just as serious a violation of the rules as killing someone on Continental grounds. So killing Wick early is as bad a violation as Wick's killing of Santino and likely subject to the same consequences.

Yes it mattered. Just in the 3rd film, it's first alluded to by both men in the library:
John Wick: Ernest. I still have time-
Ernest: It's almost up. Who's gonna know the difference?
John Wick: You sure this is what you wanna do?
Ernest: 14 million is a lot of money.

Ernest implies that he can only collect it if no one knows he killed John before he became excommunicado. A good reason that there were no witnesses. Later when the excommunicado went into effect, you have a scene with the Accountants:
narrating Accountant: John Wick, 14 million. Open contract is now in effect.
      All services are suspended.

She made it clear the contract is only active when John is excommunicado. If he is killed before then, it's for free. The Camorra may have put out the doubled bounty, but Winston had enough pull to put in the call and set the time.
